# if $f(n+1)>f(n)$ and $g(n+1)>g(n)$ and $h(n)=\max(f(n),g(n))$, prove $h=o(g)$ or $h=o(f)$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, algorithms, asymptotics

how can I prove this?

$f(n+1)>f(n)$  and $g(n+1)>g(n)$,  $h(n)=\max(f(n),g(n))$.  Prove  that $h=o(g) or h=o(f)$.

Comment: You can't. It is obviously false. (Counter-example: $f(n) = g(n) = n$, so $h(n) = n$. But $n \ne o(n)$). Maybe you meant big-O instead of little-o?

Comment: I expect you mean big-$O,$ not little-$o$. It's still false.  For $n\in\Bbb N$  let $f(2n-1)=(2n-1)!$  and $g(2n-1)=(2n)!.$ And let $f(2n)=(2n)!(2n)$ and $g(2n)=(2n)!+1$.